# POST a file from Apps Script to remote web server

Tags: google-apps-script

I am writing a Google Workspace Add-on. In this addon, I am writing an Action event handler for a button. What this Action needs to do is convert a GDOC to DOCX and then send it to an external web server using the POST http method.

The problem is that in order to POST the file, it needs to be a Blob - not the Apps Script version of Blob, just a normal JavaScript Blob. I tried to instantiate this Blob but Apps Script doesn't recognise it. I believe this is because the code isn't running inside a browser.

Does anyone know a standard approach to POST data, such as a DOCX, to an external web server from an Action?

I have the DOCX in a byte array format but I don't know what the next step is to POST it.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you post the code you are using to POST the Blob?

Comment: Base64 it and post?

Comment: Problem solved. It turns out that the Apps Script version of the Blob can be posted using the UrlFetchApp.fetch() method. I guess behind the scenes, Google converts this to a standard Blob.

Comment: @JonathanStewart Consider adding it as a answer in the answer box below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. It turns out that the Apps Script version of the Blob can be posted using the UrlFetchApp.fetch() method. I guess behind the scenes, Google converts this to a standard Blob

Answer (score 0):

The preferred and probably the only available method in apps script is [to encode the data in base64](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#base64encodewebsafedata) and send it. You can then decode it on the receiving end. The obvious disadvantage here is that it increases transfer size.